# RenderTexture with SteamVR differs from standard Unity camera

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, steamvr

I'm currently working on a project, where I'm coloring 3d objects. The code is similar to [here](https://codeartist.mx/dynamic-texture-painting/). Basically, I use an orthogonal camera that renders to a rendertexture, which is used as UV image in my material. In the beginning, it only "sees" a plane with a base image on it.

On painting, I create a 2d sprite at the correct position, in front of this render cam. This works fine.
Now, as Unity does not run smoothly with a lot of sprites, I try to reduce the load by combining the sprites into the base image with the `Texture2D.ReadPixels()` command. This new texture is then set as the new base texture. Rinse and repeat.

This approach works flawlessly if I'm using the build-in Unity camera settings. As the project is intended for VR, I ported everything into a SteamVR project.
The runtime rendering is fine as well, only the save-as-png texture function starts to break. I included the links to the different images. The first is the [Base Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6qDF.png), second the saved with "[Unity only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4M33.png)", last the saved with [SteamVR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2nGO.png) textures. I only paint green circles as sprites upon them.

As you can see, the SteamVR has several problems in comparison with the unity only version:

1. The alpha channel is detected as black, there is no fading
2. The overall resolution becomes.. unstable? (see the numbers, they are getting blockier)
3. The colors from block 1, 5 and 6 are wrong

I tried different formats for the renderTexture, UV texture (RGBA, ARGB, RGB). Apart from importing the SteamVR, nothing else has changed. What am I missing?

The rendering code is as follow:

```
Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(width, height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
tex.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, width, height), 0, 0);
tex.Apply();
plane.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.mainTexture = tex;
```

Saving with

```
var bytes = tex.EncodeToPNG();
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(fullPath + fileName, bytes);
```

If necessary, I can upload the complete project.
Thanks for your help

Thomas

Comment: Show the complete function where you're calling ReadPixels from